# iOS List of Installed Apps by User || XAMARIN FORMS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am creating an iOS application using Xamarin Forms which is a copy of an Android application written in Kotlin.
There is a section that lists all the applications installed in the current device by the user. I want to implement the same functionality in the iOS application too.

Is it possible to get the applications list in iOS through Xamarin Forms?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in iOS period.  iOS does not have any APIs to tell an app about other installed apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible on iOS and it is not possible on Android either if you target latest API levels, so in some future when those API levels become required on Google Play you won't be able to do this.

This is a huge privacy issue, as having the list of apps may reveal something very personal and private and as soon as the app has it there is nothing that prevents it to send the info to the 3rd party server.

Comment: I can see many android apps developed in kotlin are able to get installed apps list in and those apps are working in the latest version of the Android i.e. Android 12.

Comment: @DharmendraKumar as said above it does not depend on the version of Android but on the version of targeted SDK in the app. Google Play doesn't require you to target the latest SDK version, it is always far behind as Google doesn't want 90% of apps to disappear just because of that.